# ngClass and CSS with all unset unexpected outcome

Tags: html, css, angular

In my Angular 4 project, I use ngClass on an object that has a CSS class applied with unset: all inside of it. I know that ngClass adds its properties, so the expected outcome is that all the values are unset and the style elements from ngClass are added. But this is not the case, now this is very annoying because the impact is big in my case:

```
<i [ngClass]="{'material-icons':true}" class="ignore-css" >chevron_right</i>


.ignore-css {
  all: unset;
}
```

I need to unset previous CSS because I don't want the size and colors and so on... from the other icons on the page. But by all: unset; the arrow icon is not shown it just says chevron_right.

How can I unset previous CSS and get the icon?

Comment: give it its library's default css values. http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web I suspect you also unset the font-family with your unset. on a side note, CSS is supposed to be cascading, that's its nature. you can place your element in a different component, to keep all prior css changes away from it

Comment: it's ambigious 'previous CSS', make more detail!

Comment: @Stavm Indeed, the font-family was indeed unset

Comment: @fangio i'll add as answer for future searchers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it its library's [default css values](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-we%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bb).

I suspect you also unset the font-family in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `!important` keyword to the properties you have inside your material-icons class:

```
.material-icons{
   attr: value !important;
}
```

This will override the unset.

Comment: If I would know the attributes of material-icons, I could do that